# Any way to disable poi using the jquery-ui-map plugin?

Tags: jquery, mobile, google-maps-api-3, maps, jquery-ui-map

I'm trying to disable poi markers in a mobile page i'am working on.  It looks like the gmap-constructor should accept the style option.  But I can't get it to work so far.

```
 $('#map_canvas').gmap({styles:[{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]}]});
```

Any ideas?  I know this can be done without using the plugin.  I was just hoping to get it working without going that route.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center' : mapdata.origin, 
    'mapTypeControl' : true, 
    'navigationControl' : true,
    'navigationControlOptions' : {'position':google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP},
    'styles':[{'featureType': "poi.business",
        'elementType': "labels",
        'stylers': [
          { 'visibility': "off" }]}]
```

`mapdata.origin` has the lat and long.